# Is services is the best way to make http request in android

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, httprequest

Is services is the best way to make http request to php server in android?
I am currently using the AsycTask but it sometimes unfortunately stops the application so i am planning to use services.

Comment: is it crashing application you mean to say by stop

Comment: where exactly it is stopping?. BTW you can use AsycTask  and Services both for performing the background operations.

Comment: yes it's crashing the application.

Comment: @Gangulian how to use AsyncTask and Services with each other.

Comment: What exception is being thrown? you can check the logcat for the particular error. Exception is not being made because of the asynctask or service but rather because of an error in your process. ]

Answer (score 1):

You have to have good reasons for using any of them. If you want to perform something in background while app is at sleep then surely service is the way to go. AsyncTask lifecycle is based on Activity lifecycle. If Activity dies and you have some pending code inside your AsyncTask then it can cause a crash so cancelling AsyncTask before exiting the app is a good practice.

But my recommendation and the best way is here to use Google Volley Library for making http request. It takes care of everything for you. You can easily cancel the request in case of exiting the app.

Answer (score 0):

`Http request` only can be done in a non-UI thread. Because it may cause `ANR(Application Not Responding)` and is forbidden in the main thread in Android. And for `Service`, it's run on main thread by default except you set `android:process="thread-name"` when you deploy it in `AndroidManifest.xml`. So, If you want to handle with http request on your own codes, you must use `AsyncTask`, `Handler` or `HandlerThread`. But I recommend you to use [Google Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/), [android-async-http](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) or [okHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp). Because they are encapsulated well and easy to use and take care everything for you.